# SQL Compare Two Lists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query which will return me a row based on matching two lists.

I have a table with the example data

```
ThreadId     EntityId
1            50
1            51
2            50
2            51
2            52
3            50
3            53
```

I'm trying to find the ThreadId where the list of EntityIds exactly matches a list of Ids i'm passing in.

Example results

```
ThreadId = 1 WHEN EntityIds IN (50, 51)
ThreadId = 2 WHEN EntityIds IN (50, 51, 52)
ThreadId = 3 WHEN  EntityIds IN (50, 53)
ThreadId = NULL WHEN EntityIds IN (50, 52) -- NULL because there is no thread with just these two EntityIds
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Neil

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but do you mean you want some code that takes a list of entity ids, matches it to the table and returns the thread id if there is a match?

Comment: Hi Robbie, yes that's exactly right

Comment: How will the input list be presented - as an SP parameter or in a table?

Comment: As an SP parameter, I have a table type parameter: CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Int64List] AS TABLE([Item] [bigint] NOT NULL)

Comment: I'd be tempted to flatten the data on both sides so you're matching a CSV, PSV or similar.

Comment: That's not possible as I have other columns in the example data table which are used elsewhere in my application.

Comment: Sorry, not in situ - in a temp table/table variable...

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Matcher]
    @Source AS SourceType READONLY
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @RetVal INT;

        DECLARE @MatchString VARCHAR(MAX);

        DECLARE @TargetSet TABLE
            (
              threadid INT ,
              entities VARCHAR(MAX) ,
              processed BIT DEFAULT 0
            );

        DECLARE @newcsv VARCHAR(MAX);

        DECLARE @currentthread INT;

        INSERT  INTO @TargetSet
                ( threadid
                )
                SELECT DISTINCT
                        threadid
                FROM    TheData;

        -- Flatten the source string

        SET @MatchString = ( SELECT SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ','
                                                        + CAST(s.EntityId AS VARCHAR)
                                                FROM    @Source s
                                                ORDER BY s.EntityId
                                              FOR
                                                XML PATH('')
                                              ), 2, 200000) AS CSV
                           );       

        -- Flatten the target data

        WHILE ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    @TargetSet
                WHERE   processed = 0
              ) > 0
            BEGIN

                SET @currentthread = ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                threadid
                                       FROM     @TargetSet
                                       WHERE    processed = 0
                                     );

                SET @newcsv = ( SELECT  SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ','
                                                            + CAST(EntityId AS VARCHAR)
                                                    FROM    TheData
                                                    WHERE   ThreadId = @currentthread
                                                    ORDER BY EntityId
                                                  FOR
                                                    XML PATH('')
                                                  ), 2, 200000) AS CSV
                              );

                UPDATE  @TargetSet
                SET     entities = @newcsv ,
                        processed = 1
                WHERE   threadid = @currentthread;

            END;

        -- Perform the match

        SET @RetVal = ( SELECT  threadid
                        FROM    @TargetSet
                        WHERE   entities = @MatchString
                      );            

        SELECT  @RetVal;

    END;
```

I've lifted the table-->CSV code from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/) but there are plenty of other examples kicking around the web if this doesn't take your fancy.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`.  If you want an *exact* match:

```
select threadid
from threadentitys
group by threadid
having sum(case when entityid in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 3 and
       sum(case when entityid not in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The first condition counts the number of matches.  The "3" says that there are three matches -- which (assuming no duplicates in the table) means that all match.  The second says that no other entities match.